# Adding handler only once

Tags: jquery

This is how I've set up my functions (the code in codeblock). I'm using this method as they're dealing with dynamically created elements. Could I try var additionFunction = function () { do stuff that requires $(this) } and have
 $(document).on('click' , ".addition" , additionFunction); For this I'd need to know how to pass $(this) to additionFunction.

```
             $(document).on('click' , ".addition" , function(event) {

              //do stuff that requires $(this)
              //the problem is that every click adds new handler and I can't wrap my head 
             //around the problem of how to do the necessary changes and still have access 
             //to $(this) which is in this case particular ".addition" (there are many).


              });
```

The messy code that was requested:

```
                  $(document).on('click' , ".addition" , function(event) {



            $("#form2").show();

            var nameforfolder;
            var _this = this;
            var this2 = $(this).parent().parent().parent().prev().text();

        $("#form2").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
        });


            var asd = 0;

            $(".submitfolder").click(function() {
            var data3 = $("#form2 :input").serialize();
            var data4 = $("#form2 :input").val();
            nameforfolder = data4;

            /*$.post( $("#form2").attr("action"),data3, function(info) {

            var asd = info;
            $("#form2").hide();

            }); */
            $.ajax({
                url: "userfolders.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {bar2: data4,
                folderparent: this2},
                    success: function() {
                    asd = 1;

                    $("#form2").hide();

       if (asd > 0) {


        var folders = $(_this).parent().children(".folder").length;
        var count =( 1 + folders);
        var folderName = nameforfolder;
        var addFolder = ("<div class=folder> </div>");
        var addFolderImg = '<img class=folderImg src="folder-icon.png">' ;
        var addFolderName = ("<h3 class=foldName>" + folderName + "</h3>");
        var addFolderMenu = ("<div class=folderMenu style=overflow:auto></div>");
        var addFolderMenuIcon = '<img class=folderMenuAdd src="plus-icon.png">' ;
        //var expandedAddText2 = '<img class=addText2 src="text.png">' ;
        var addLi_Remove = '<img class=liRemove src="x-icon.png">' ; 
        var addUl_Menu = ("<ul class=ul> </ul>");



    console.log(_this);


        if (folders == 0) {


            $(_this).parent().append(addFolder); 
            } 
            else {
            $(_this).parent().children(".folder").last().after(addFolder);
        };


        $(_this).parent().children(".folder").last().append(addFolderImg);
        $(_this).parent().children(".folder").last().append(addFolderName);
        $(_this).parent().children(".folder").last().append(addFolderMenu);
        $(_this).parent().children(".folder").children(".folderMenu").hide();
        $(_this).parent().children(".folder").children(".folderMenu").last().append(addFolderMenuIcon);
        //$(_this).parent().children(".folder").children(".folderMenu").last().append(expandedAddText2);
        $(_this).parent().children(".folder").children(".folderMenu").last().append(addLi_Remove);
        $(_this).parent().children(".folder").children(".folderMenu").last().append(addUl_Menu);


            } else {


        };
    }

    });


            }); 







            //createFolder(nameforfolder);


    });
```

Comment: Do you want to ignore all clicks except the first? If not, could you clarify your problem?

Comment: I'd like the function to fire only once, but now after multiple clicks it fires multiple times.

Comment: *Once with each click, no matter if I have clicked it previously.

Comment: please post the addition function and some html

Comment: It's not possible to answer this without seeing the circumstances you instantiate those click handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no reason to attach events inside an event function

```
$(".submitfolder").click(function() {
  ...
});
$("#form2").submit(function(e) {
  ...
});
$(document).on('click', ".addition", function(event) {
  ...
});
```

if you do want to nest them for some reason you should detach event before attaching a new one like so:

```
$(document).on('click', ".addition", function(event) {
  $(".submitfolder").off("click");
  $(".submitfolder").click(function() {
    ...
  });
  $("#form2").off("submit");
  $("#form2").submit(function(e) {
    ...
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, your nested example worked! As a beginner I tend to do things the wrong way but I'm learning. I still don't feel comfortable with functions and how to use them properly (passing data between them for example, which is why I have nested my functions) as this is my first website project ever and I just started doing.

Comment: @Still.Learning This is what stackoverflow is for. You can click the check on the left of the answer to mark it as the correct one.

Comment: Thank you and for the developers of this site then, heh. Marked.

Answer (score 0):

try this. is this what you want. function will fire only once. as an example I put an alert.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">

</style>

<body>
 
<button id="mybutton">CLICK ON ME , I WILL FIRE ONCE</button>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  var numberofclicks = 1;
  $("#mybutton").click(function(e){
    if (numberofclicks == 1) {
      alert("I'm fired ..... !");
      //do your implementation here.
    }
    numberofclicks +=1;
  });
  
});





</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Using your answer as an example, if I click #mybutton once, it fires once, but if I click it after that it does not fire at all. I want it to fire once again, with each click. The problem with my code is this: first click will fire once, second click will fire twice. See?

Comment: show your `html` or `dynamic` part that you have considered in the question. that will help to get an idea of what you want.